# Is it possible to have case insensitive targets with GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

Is it possible to design a makefile so that

```
make program_name
```

produces the same result as

```
make PROGRAM_NAME
```

?

I know I can do the following in the makefile

```
program_name : PROGRAM_NAME
```

but I don't know if there is a way to streamline this for multiple targets.  We have about 50 or so targets.

Comment: GNU-make v.4.2.90 on Windows treats targets with case-insensitivity. I think it's been the case since forever. Something to do with '-D HAVE_CASE_INSENSITIVE_FS'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crude but effective:

```
PROGRAM_NAME:
    @echo do something for $@

ANOTHER_TARGET:
    @echo do something else for $@

YET_ANOTHER:
    @echo and something else for $@

% :
    @$(MAKE) `echo $@ | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]`
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work for the most part.  The only problem is that if I have a directory called program_name/ where I call make, it doesn't seem to work.  But it will if I type Program_nAme, or the like, or if I type in a name that doesn't happen to be a directory there?  Any ideas on how I can ignore directory names?

Comment: @Chance, it can be done but it ain't pretty. If there aren't many such directories, I'd suggest adding `program_name: PROGRAM_NAME`.